# Where/how should I discuss a rejected edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Where and how can I start a discussion on an edit I suggested that was rejected? Get in private/personal contact with the reviewer? It [seems here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146761/can-i-contest-a-rejected-edit?answertab=active#146764) is better, but if so: How to get the attention of the reviewer (e.g. is it possible to tag someone)? Follow [this example](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2057/why-couldnt-i-edit-question-79622) for my title (naming the question number)?

<sub>N.B.: I ask this question after [this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4236/do-i-get-a-notification-when-my-edit-is-not-accepted/4240#4240) & comment by Eliah Kagen.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Now that I saw the edit in question I admit that I rejected it too hastily. I am sorry for that. Indeed the answers to this peculiar question are likewise applicable to a wider range of video playing applications thus your edit was a good one indeed.

This is not an excuse but an explanation: we are faced with quite a lot of minor edits recently. Unfortunately I mistook yours as one of those. I hope I will take more care in the future to avoid those things happening.

Yet, I can not promise to be without fail. If this happens again with me or anybody else it is best to discuss the matter. There are several ways to do so:

- Ask a question here in Meta  .
- Join us in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) where many of us are around quite often.
- Address a certain user by preceding a comment or chat message by their name (e.g. `@Takkat` to let the system give them a notice (*"Ping"*).

Last not least:

- **Do not hesitate to suggest your edit again.**